# boost thread and "sleep"

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I've wrote some functions like

> openWebPage()
>   fillInforMation()
>   submitNow()

they called by button click event.

how ever I want to do it in a thread,Then I created a structure which contain those function and then pass it as parameter to boost::thread,it works fine,every function gets called.

but if the internet is slow,some function will not success,so what I want to do is something like this:

```
openWebPage() 
wait 20 seconds 
fillInformation() 
wait 5 seconds
submitnow()
```

that wait function,how to do it in boost::thread? by the way I am using gcc and gtk if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you question, the function you are looking for is [`boost::this_thread::sleep`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.sleep).

But if there is an error in one of you functions, is it really okay to continue? For example if `openWebPage` fails, can you really use the other functions? Errors should never be ignored as that may cause further errors down the road.